# Use ORDER BY in SQL Server starting from row 2 onwards only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table that always returns multiple of rows, in which I use those rows as value in a combo box in VB.NET. In those rows, the 1st row is the data that is set to be as default value. Now, the rest of the rows must be ordered alphabetically to make it easier to read. I'm trying to use `ROW_NUMBER()` right now, is there a concise way for me to do this.

Using this structure as basis.

```
tbl_Sample
col_ID - int
col_description - varchar(30)
```

with these datas present

```
col_ID  |  col_description
--------------------------
1       |  Default_Value
2       |  a_value2
3       |  a_value2
4       |  a_value5
5       |  a_value1
6       |  a_value3
```

i want to have a query that returns something like this

```
col_ID  |  col_description
--------------------------
1       |  Default_Value
5       |  a_value1
2       |  a_value2
3       |  a_value2
6       |  a_value3
4       |  a_value5
```

as for the query, as I said I'm testing up ROW_NUMBER() along with OVER and ORDER BY, since ordering it by `col_description` will not work since the arrangement of the descriptions in alphabetical order will alter the `Default_Value`'s row number which must remain in row 1.

Comment: Create one extra column in sql  like case when colid=1 then 1 case when colid=5 then 2 else colid end end as ColOrder.now you can easily order by ColOrder.Any further problem ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
row_number() over(order by case when col_description = 'Default_Value' then 0 else 1 end ASC, col_description ASC)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I see no reason to use `row_number()` here. you can use the `case` in the `order by` clause directly:

```
SELECT col_ID, col_description
FROM tbl_Sample
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col_description = 'Default_Value' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, col_description
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to GROUP BY column, using PARTITION BY, like this:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()
OVER(PARTITION BY col_description ORDER BY CASE WHEN col_description = 'Default_Value' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, col_description ASC) AS RN
FROM tbl_Sample
```